# Problema con impresión en rotativa ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, rotativa

Acabo de instalar rotativa para generar archivos pdf a partir de mis vistas. Actualmente estoy usando Asp Net Core 2.0.
El problema es el siguiente, cuando intento seguir la documentación de Rotativa me lanza un error:

> *Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Rotativa.AspNetCore.ViewAsPdf' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult'*

```
public ActionResult Imprimir()
{
    var PDFResult = new ActionAsPdf("Details")
    {
        FileName = "Reporte.PDF"                
    };

    return PDFResult;
}
```

Alguna idea de que es lo que estará sucediendo?

Comment: Escribe el código en vez de usar imágenes. También el error, por favor.

Comment: Lo acabo de editar

Comment: Este error que has puesto aquí no es el mismo que aparecía en la imagen. Creo que el de la imagen lo puedes solucionar así `return PDFResult as ActionResult`. Y el error que has puesto ahora pertenece a otra parte de tu código.

Answer (score 1):

Después de buscar un poco encontre que mi problema se debía al hecho de que estaba usando una libreria de rotativa incorrecta, en mi caso que trabajo con asp.net core era necesario usar la libreria de rotativa provista para net core dejo un enlace para quien guste revisarlo, en mi caso soluciono mi problema.

[Rotativa Net Core MVC](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/3/21/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-pdf-a-partir-de-una-vista-en-aspnet-core-mvc)